# Doing computation in GORM criteria query

Tags: hibernate, grails, criteria, grails-orm

This is basic domain class

```
Location {
  double lat;
  double lng
}
```

I want to convert this query to GORM  form

```
SELECT name, lat, lng, SQRT(
    POW(69.1 * (lat -  LAT1), 2) +
    POW(69.1 * (LNG1- lng) * COS(lat / 57.3), 2)) AS distance
FROM location ORDER BY distance;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run HQL queries that select individual columns with executeQuery:

```
    def results= location.executeQuery('SELECT name, lat, lng, SQRT(
    POW(69.1 * (lat -  LAT1), 2) +
    POW(69.1 * (LNG1- lng) * COS(lat / 57.3), 2)) AS distance
    FROM location ORDER BY distance')
```

This will return a List of Object[], e.g.

```
for (row in results) {
   String name= row[0]
   String lat= row[1]
   ...
}
```

Comment: I want it in GORM form using `createCriteria`

Comment: maybe this will help http://www.grails.org/doc/1.2.1/ref/Domain%20Classes/createCriteria.html

Comment: your query says no column found `distance` in order by clause

Comment: you need to put the whole calcultion in order by clause like:
order by SQRT(
    POW(69.1 * (lat -  LAT1), 2) +
    POW(69.1 * (LNG1- lng) * COS(lat / 57.3), 2))